# Print/Output variable values to immediate window

Tags: algorithm, vba, debug-print

I'm trying to write some vba that will print the values which satisfy the below constraints:

```
b * k = t * k
```

`lambda = r * (k - 1) / (t - 1)`, where `(t - 1) >= (k - 1)` & `lambda` must be an integer.

Here is the algorithm:

```
Sub BIBDs()

Dim t, b, k, r As Integer
Dim lambda As String

For t = 2 To 50
    For b = 2 To 20
        For r = 1 To 20
            For k = 3 To 5
                If b * k = t * k & (t - 1) >= (k - 1) Then
                lambda = r * (k - 1) / (t - 1)
                    If lambda = Int(lambda) Then
                        Debug.Print t, b, r, k, lambda
                    End If
                End If
            Next k
        Next r
    Next b
Next t

End Sub
```

Nothing is printed in the "Immediate" window. I'm not sure it there is something wrong with the algorithm or my print method. Specifically, I'm not sure if I'm correctly checking that lambda is an integer.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Apologies @duDE, I accidentally posted it before I was finished.

Comment: duDE is correct in his answer.  Additionally, If lambda = Int(lambda) Then is always going to be true...  Why are you trying to check that?

Comment: I'm trying to see if the value of lambda is an whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
If b * k = t * k And (t - 1) >= (k - 1) Then
```

instead of

```
If b * k = t * k & (t - 1) >= (k - 1) Then
```

The **& operator** in VBA is not the same like **logical And operator**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!